# How to make query according to my problem in Laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

[image]

Image drive link: [Click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaD42YnFy8AhuOueZ60VNnFWq651hqyn/view?usp=sharing)

My database looks like the [photos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaD42YnFy8AhuOueZ60VNnFWq651hqyn/view?usp=sharing). Now I need a query result that i describe in two step for better understandind.

- ***step 01:*** I need these result where syllab_subjects have a specific syllab id. $query_step1 = SyllabSubject::where('syllab_id',$given_id)->get()
- ***step 02:*** I need only these subject which is not exist in $query_step1. Simply, In $query_step1 check which subject_id is not available when compare with subject table.

For better understanding, if we make query for syllab_id 10, then query result returns **"science"** and if syllab_id 5 then it returns **"English and Science"**

Comment: Have you set up models with relationships for these tables? It looks like you haven't.  What you need is a model like

Comment: It has no relationship. I just need a query that returns subject table according my way

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up models with relationships for these tables? It looks like you haven't.  What you need is a model like

```php
class Subject extends Model
{
 public function syllab() {
  return $this->hasMany(Syllab::class):
 }
}
```

and

```php
class Syllab extends Model
{
 public function subject(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class); 
 }
}
```

Then you can get the details like

```php
$syllab = Syllab::find(10);
$syllab->subjects->pluck('name');
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Please read my problem carefully. I already upvoted but I think the relation should be subject and syllab_subjects.  I need only these subjects these are not exist in syllab_subjects table for a specific id. Thanks for your consideration !